# Testing TeXLive 2019 (MacTeX) with TRIP.TEX

Tags: plain-tex, web

While browsing through Don Knuth's publications on TeX, I was referred to the file `tripman.pdf` on my MacTeX distribution. As TeXnicians may know, this file explains the purpose of the `TRIP` test and how it is to be used, along with the provision of the source to the input files and the correct output. I decided (foolishly?) to try out the test for myself, which is where the issue begins.

I have two questions:

1. In step 2 of Appendix A, how should I go about modifying `INITEX` so that the parameters are set as specified there? I have heard of 'change files' which modify the output of `weave`, `tangle`, `cweave`, and `ctangle` without changing the original `WEB` or `CWEB` file, but it is my understanding that such files cannot modify the behaviour of `UNIX` executables. **Without modifying the source of TeX**, how can this be done?
2. In step 4, should the version of `INITEX` being run be the unmodified version or the modified version in step 2? I assume that, for debugging purposes, the modified version should be used, but I would just like to confirm.

Any further information regarding potential challenges in conducting this test would be very much appreciated. I am a frequent (though admittedly unskilled) user of LaTeX who has recently begun reading the works of Don Knuth on typesetting and typography and may need a little assistance in understanding such materials.

My machine is a Mac running TeXLive 2019 in the form of MacTeX. If any other required information is missing, please request them in the comments.

Thank you.

---

This is my first foray into TeX.SX, and so the quality of my questions may be subpar. I apologise for any faux pas I may have committed in the course of writing this question, and I welcome all suggestions as to how the above may be improved. Any suggestions as to appropriate tagging would be greatly appreciated. Please, be gentle.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx,  +1 for bravery.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for the compliment! I did not expect you here (no offence).

Comment: The `trip` test is for developers to check their change file that
brings `tex.web` to a machine. The answer to question 1 is
therefore: Yes you have to add the listed changes to your change
file. And yes the modified version of `INITEX` is used in steps 3 and
4. `texlive` used to have a directory in its source tree
`texk/web2c/triptrap` where you can find the results of `trip` and
`trap` (for `METAFONT`). If you are able to compile the source you can
try to redo the steps.

Comment: @UdoWermuth thanks. Could you kindly direct me to resources documenting the syntax of change files? I couldn’t locate anything of the sort on my distribution.

Comment: Welcome! You'll have to build the TeX binaries from source — for TeX Live, see [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/build.html) and [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html). Once you've got that process working end-to-end (and have a binary to test), you can try out the trip test with change files or whatever: for change files you can see the [WEB manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/knuth/webman.pdf); the syntax is basically `@x ... @y ... @z` where the first `...` stands for the “before” set of lines and the second `...` stands for the “after” set of lines.

Comment: Change files are described in the manual (link see other comment) on page 10 item 11.

Comment: Thank you both! Feel free to add your responses as answers so that I can resolve the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of `\TeX` is done in `tex.web`. This file is a
generic implementation which must be tailored to an operating system
or, in general, to a specific computer and a Pascal compiler. For
example, file name conventions and the input and output procedures
must be changed to meet the specifications of a particular system and
if the Pascal compiler does not allow an `else` path in a `case`
statement, for example, then several places in the source have to be
changed.

Therefore the programs `TANGLE` and `WEAVE` do not only read a single
`WEB` file but they can handle a change file for such a file. So to
compile `\TeX` you need `tex.web` and `tex.ch` that contains the
changes for your machine.

To check that your change file does not change `\TeX` in a way that
makes your implementation incompatible, i.e., the same .tex file
generates an output different from other `\TeX` implementations, one
condition is that the `trip` test must be passed. It requires a special
version of `INITEX` with predefined values for certain compile-time
parameters to make the output of the test comparable. Thus to perform
a `trip` test you must build a special version of `\TeX` and that
means that you have to tangle `tex.web` with your change file and to
compile the resulting Pascal output with your Pascal compiler.

The additional changes for your local change file are described in detail in the test procedure and there
the steps for the test are explained. The results must be compared to
the output generated by the default `\TeX` system. These results are
listed in the test procedure too and they might change with every new
`tex.web`.

On `CTAN` you find the relevant documents and sources:

(1) https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex contains `tex.web`
and `tripman.tex` and all required files for the `trip` test;

(2) https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/web contains `TANGLE`
and `WEAVE` source code and the `WEB` manual;

(3) https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/local/tex/initex.ch
is an untested and not complete example of a change file for the `trip` test.

(See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/unix for complete systems
for different Pascal compilers; note, however, I don't recommend to
use these systems.)

If you download
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/lib/webmac.tex you can
(i) run `weave tex.web` or `weave tangle.web` etc. without a change
file to get a *.tex file that can be processed by `plain tex` and (ii)
read about the generic programs. Of course, you can add a change file
and see what happens then.

If you download
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Source/texlive-20190408-source.tar.xz
you can find the directory `texk\web2c\triptrap` with the trip test
results for this texlive system. (You must be able to handle `xz` and
`tar` files, of course.)